# Java method keeps running before returning value

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my program to return the value after running through the last for loop, but for some reason it loops back multiple times after the for loop. I added a System.print right before return to test what was happening, and it loops many more times. The first result is what I expected, but the looping causes it the be incorrect. How can I stop this from happening?

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RussianExpo 
{
    static int counter = 0;
    static int[] intArray = new int[25];
    static int value = 1;

    public static int expomod(int a, int b, int n)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (b == 0)
            {
                intArray[counter] = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (b==1)
            {
                intArray[counter] = a;
                break;
            }

            if (b>1)
            {
                if((b & 1) == 0); 
                {
                    intArray[counter] = 1;
                    a = (a*a);
                    b = (int) Math.floor(b/2);
                    counter++;
                    expomod(a,b,n);
                }
                if((b & 1) == 1);
                {
                    intArray[counter] = a;
                    a = (a*a);
                    b = (int) Math.floor(b/2);
                    counter++;
                    expomod(a,b,n);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)  
        {
            if(intArray[i]>0)
            {
                value = value*intArray[i];
                value = value % n;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(value);
        return value; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a");
        int a = SC.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter b");
        int b = SC.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter n");
        int n = SC.nextInt();

        System.out.println(expomod(a,b,n));

        SC.close();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter a
30
Enter b
2
Enter n
35

25
30
15
15
```

Comment: You are using Scanner.nextInt(), but you are not dealing with new lines.

Comment: I believe you're getting multiple prints at the end of expomod because you're calling it recursively.

Comment: @NomadMaker I know that I'm calling it recursively, but why would it go again after System.out.println(value);? I'm not calling for it to run again after that line.

Comment: What is expomod supposed to do? There are a few red flags in this code. The return values of the recursive calls don't get used. Also the static variables shared between the recursive calls makes it difficult to grok.

Comment: @PaulRooney [Here's a picture](https://i.imgur.com/83wUw57.png)

Comment: This looks like you are trying to write two different exponentiation algorithms in the same method. Delete everything before the for loop, and initialise the array there to start with 1. The recursive part is just a different way of trying to do the same thing, so it's superfluous even if you fix it.

Comment: As for why it still prints after returning, I suspect you have the misconception that when a recursive function returns, it causes all other calls of the same function to return too. That is not how recursive functions are executed; when a recursive call returns, the call above it receives that return value and resumes executing. I have made an interactive model of how recursive functions are executed, which may help you to understand: https://werp.site/cs-toys/recursion.html

Comment: @Connor As kaya3 said, when a function is called, it completes and then the calling function resumes. So when expomod() calls itself, the 2nd expomod() is almost finished, it prints value, then it returns. The original function, also expomod() eventually prints its value and returns.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting a break within the for loop to exit the loop? Set the break after `value = value % n;`

Answer (score 1):

Could be wrong, I'm not sure what the intention of the program is, but I think your issue is the recursive calls

```
 if((b & 1) == 1);
                {
                    intArray[counter] = a;
                    a = (a*a);
                    b = (int) Math.floor(b/2);
                    counter++;
                    expomod(a,b,n); //This recalls the function!
                }
```

If the first value is correct then it would appear to be the answer after the function has run it's complete course, the subsequent values come from the returns as the stack returns from the recursive calls, removing the  expomod(a,b,n) call from inside the expomod() function may fix this issue.

Short answer:

remove any calls to expomod(a,b,n) from inside expomod() and see if you get the result you want.